# My images only display in google chrome

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

On some browser's(Firefox and IE)my images won't load at all.

Can someone just explain what is the best practices for correctly formatting  element ?

For example within the src tag should "%" and "_" be present ?

Or else is there's something wrong with my code ?

Comment: src="C:\Users\James\Desktop\Job\Neecal\Misc\Neecal%20project_2\img\72\DSCN0515.jpg"

Comment: It's on local computer so maybe it should be file:///C:\

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention, it's on my local computer. @Joni I don't fully understand could you elaborate ? with an example ?

Comment: src="file:///C:\Users\James\Desktop\Job\Neecal\Misc\Neecal%20project_2\img\72\DSCN0515.j‌​pg"

Comment: I'm not sure how browsers handle backslashes so maybe this `src="file:///C:/Users/James/Desktop/Job/Neecal/Misc/Neecal%20project_2/img/72/DSCN0515.j‌​pg"`

Comment: Thanks Joni it's working beautifully ^_^                                      Now to solve the next problem ^_^

Answer (score 3):

Please don not provide any space for any names , space takes like % which browser does not render.If you want name of an image like background image so put like that background_image.jpg
Hope the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code: < img src="/images/chrome.gif">

Comment: I forgot to mention, it's on my local computer. I don't understand what you mean.